# Meteor 1.4.1.1 to Meteor 1.4.1.2

Tags: meteor

I would like to upgrade `Meteor 1.4.1.1` to `Meteor 1.4.1.2`.  Please can someone advise?

I run the following:

> meteor update --release 1.4.1.2

And I get the following error:

```
E:\Development\IDE\ionic-apps\theWhoZoo\api>meteor update --release 1.4.1.2
C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:165
      throw error;
      ^

Error: unexpected eof
    at decorate (C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\abstract.js:67:36)
```

Must I delete the following directory first?

```
C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\.meteor
```

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7766). Looks like this is a bug in Meteor, to be fixed in Meteor 1.4.2.

To fix:

with Command Prompt (cmd.exe)

> ```
> C:\Users\IEUser\my-app>set METEOR_WAREHOUSE_URLBASE=https://d3fm2vapipm3k9.cloudfront.net
>
> C:\Users\IEUser\my-app>meteor
> ```

With PowerShell

> ```
> PS C:\Users\IEUser\my-app> $Env:METEOR_WAREHOUSE_URLBASE="https://d3fm2vapipm3k9.cloudfront.net"
> PS C:\Users\IEUser\my-app> meteor
> ```

Also try:

> meteor update --patch

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is the error of your meteor project, not the update issue.

For that, you have to go to your promise_server.js file and rectify changes over there.

Then run the command `meteor update --release version`.